# Angular http get

Tags: angularjs, http, get

Есть код:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($http, $scope){

var get1 = $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get1')
        .success(function (result){
            console.log('success', result);
            $scope.books = result;
        })
        .error(function (result){
            console.log('error');
        });

var get2 = $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get2')
        .success(function (result){
            console.log('success', result);
            $scope.books2 = result;
        })
        .error(function (result){
            console.log('error');
        });

    if (get1 || get2) {
        var get3 = $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get3')
            .success(function (result){
                console.log('success', result);
                $scope.books3 = result;
            })
            .error(function (result){
                console.log('error');
            });
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }

});
```

Что написать в условии выполнения get3, чтобы если первый или второй не сработали, не сработал бы и третий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `get`, как и любой другой метод [сервиса $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) возвращает Promise.

Для того, чтобы дождаться завершения *всех* Promise, необходимо воспользоваться методом [.all из сервиса $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Таким образом, чтобы запустить третий запрос, только когда завершились *успешно* два предыдущих, код может принять следующий вид:

```
$q.all([get1,get2]).then(function(){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get3');
})
```

---

Небольшое отступление: методы `success` и `error` устарели и в новых версиях вместо них следует использовать `then(successCallback,errorCallback)`

Например:

- было

  ```
  $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get3')
      .success(function (result){
          console.log('success', result);
          $scope.books3 = result;
      })
      .error(function (result){
          console.log('error');
      });
  ```
- стало

  ```
  $http.get('http://localhost:3001/get3')
      .then(function success(response){
          console.log('success', response.data);
          $scope.books3 = response.data;
      }, function error(response){
          console.log('error');
      });
  ```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! Я пробовал Ang 1.6, но он "TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function".
Как тогда нужно написать в данном случае then для 1 и 2 get?

Comment: @Alexey, добавил пример

Comment: Теперь ошибка "GET http://localhost:3001/get1 404 (Not Found), XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3001/get1"

Comment: @Alexey, это тебе намекают - что ты неверный адрес для запроса указал:)

Comment: Ну как же не правильный, если до этого работало, я переписал только then, а не адресс. Если написать как было, все работает.

Comment: @Alexey, а вот так: ответ, что такой страницы нет, ты получаешь от сервера, ангуляр тут ни причем, следовательно адрес неверен

Comment: Ну как же нет, если я ее написал в ноде, и опять же говорю, если вернуть success и error, то все работает, а с then нет

Comment: @Alexey, а вот так и нет, then и success никак не влияют куда будет идти запрос. Это определяется только параметром функции `get` и даже если ты их полностью уберешь - результат будет таким же. если у тебя работает с success, а с then нет, значит ты меняешь что-то где-то еще. Ищи различия

Comment: Код один в один как ты кинул

Comment: @Alexey, без [mcve] нет смысла дальше обсуждать. Если сможешь сделать пример, который будет воспроизводить твою ошибку только с then, а с success/error не будет - то можно будет дальше разбираться, на данный момент код полностью рабочий и ошибка говорит лишь о том. что сервер ничего не нашел по указанному адресу

Comment: Нашел ошибку, спасибо"

Comment: @Alexey, и в чем она была?:)

Comment: заменил не тот файл